Angular :leave animation in child elements create cascading delay
I have an animation sequence for enter and leave in my app.
animations: [
    trigger('barSlideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(80px)'}),
        animate('0.4s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.7, 0.1, 1.0)', style({transform: 'translateY(0px)'}))
      ]) ,
      transition(':leave', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(0px)'}),
        animate('0.35s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0.0, 0.8, 0.15)', style({transform: 'translateY(80px)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]

Child elements in this component also have their own animations.
On :enter everything works as expected, but on :leave I assume that children animations are delayed by parent animation duration because ngDestroy is not fired yet. It ends up with children simply disappear because parent is destroyed.
I there any solution to fix this to fire in same moment? Children animations are binded to host because these are reusable components.
Thanks.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

If you do something liket this:
    trigger('parentCollapse', [
  transition(':enter', [style({ height: '0', visibility: 'hidden', overflow: "hidden" }), animate('10ms ease-in', style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE })), query('@slowCollapse', animateChild(), {optional: true})]),
  transition(':leave', [query('@slowCollapse', animateChild()), style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE, overflow: "hidden" }), animate('300ms ease-out', style({ height: '0', visibility: 'hidden' }))])
]),
trigger('slowCollapse', [
  transition(':enter', [style({ height: '0', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden', overflow: "hidden" }), animate('600ms ease-in', style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, minHeight: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE }))]),
  transition(':leave', [style({ height: AUTO_STYLE, minHeight: AUTO_STYLE, visibility: AUTO_STYLE, overflow: "hidden" }), animate('600ms ease-out', style({ height: '0', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' }))])
])

Than the animation searches for childs and triggers the animation

Improve formatting on your code
